# Entity reference field with custom class

Tags: entities

I created two content type Writer & Book. Writer has entity reference field that link to Book nodes. When display Writer node, I like the book nodes that attached to it display as list and the first list item has CSS class of "first".

Output the list is simple but I couldn't figure out how to add that CSS class.

If possible, I prefer do it with template.php or node--content_type.tpl.php flies, not using JQuery, Views or another modules.

Appreciate any suggestions, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your tempalate.php file, add the following for that field. This is the standard implementation of [theme_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7). I added the line if `($delta == 1) $classes .= ' first';` to add the class.

```
function yourthemename_field__yourfieldname ($variables) {
  $output = '';

  // Render the label, if it's not hidden.
  if (!$variables ['label_hidden']) {
    $output .= '<div class="field-label"' . $variables ['title_attributes'] . '>' . $variables ['label'] . ':&nbsp;</div>';
  }

  // Render the items.
  $output .= '<div class="field-items"' . $variables ['content_attributes'] . '>';
  foreach ($variables ['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $classes = 'field-item ' . ($delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
    //add your class here
    if ($delta == 1) $classes .= ' first';
    $output .= '<div class="' . $classes . '"' . $variables ['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . drupal_render($item) . '</div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';

  // Render the top-level DIV.
  $output = '<div class="' . $variables ['classes'] . '"' . $variables ['attributes'] . '>' . $output . '</div>';


  return $output;
}
```

Furthermore, you can change this for different view modes and different bundles. The rest is in [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7).

Comment: Thank you so much. It fixed my problem. I've been searching it for like a day and I know there is something I can do about the class just don't know where. Thanks again!

Comment: You welcome. :)